# Coming back from intent, do something

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an android application which is using listView. After clicking on any item on the list it shows you AlertDialog where you can chose either edit or delete. After clicking edit it starts a new intent sending some extra strings to fill up the form for editing. I would like to refresh the list after I click on button save in that EditActivity.

I have read about  `notifyDataSetChanged()` and I think it could work I just would like to know if there is any method which is in `MainClass` (listView class) and it is executed right after I came back from intent, right after clicking save button in EditActivity.

Or may I just add `notifyDataSetChanged()` method after I start an activity in the `MainActivity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class yourClass extends ListActivity {

//define a class variable here.
private ArrayAdapter<Friend> adapter;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

//Change this line  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Friend>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, db.getAllFriends()));

to

adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<Friend>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, db.getAllFriends());

 setListAdapter(adapter);
}


@Override
public void onResume(){
super.onResume();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}


}
```

Comment: This will refresh the listview every time the user focuses this activity, that's what `onResume` means. It's not good for performence. You have to refresh the list only if data has changed. Be careful !

Comment: @mansoulx: i know this, but i think he is new to android, thats why i gave him a simple solution... Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can add listView.notifyDataSetChanged() in your activity onResume() function.

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
super.onResume();
yourListView.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: add this function into your main activity :)

Comment: Thank you this looks as exactly what I wanted but I have additional question if you dont mind. By "yourListView" you meant a reference to my list view but I dont have anything like this created. Did you get me? I have it only here: protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, final int position,
   long id)

Comment: should I do it within this method l.notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: yes, youListView reference to listview you have in your activity.

Comment: Yes but I dont have any reference on my list view. I dont know why. I have only this: setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Friend>(this,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, db.getAllFriends()));

Comment: Yes I do, I think i found out.. I can use getListView.

Comment: then replace it to notifyDataSetChanged() instead of yourlistView.notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50025/discussion-between-ondrej-zatokar-tokar-and-ahmad-raza)

Answer (score 1):

Use the method `startActivityForResult()` when opening your `EditActivity` then implement `onActivityResult` method in your main class. There you will be able to use `notifyDataSetChanged`

**[Read this from the doc](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)**

Answer (score 1):

use `startActivityForResult` to call your `EditActivity` (*this isn't simplest way to do what you want but is good way to do*), by using this you can find out what is the result of your edit

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, EditActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

In your EActivity set the data which you want to return back to MainActivity

```
 Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
 returnIntent.putExtra("result",YOUR_RESULT); // skip if you do not want to return special result
 setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
 finish();
```

if you want to send cancel action (in your case fail edit) use this

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);        
finish();
```

Now in your `MainActivity` class write following code for `onActivityResult()` method

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

  if (requestCode == 1) {

     if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
         String result=data.getStringExtra("result");   // result sent from EditActivity    
         listViewAdapter. notifyDataSetChanged();         
     }
     if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {    
         //Write your code if there's no result
     }
  }
}//onActivityResult
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand. Is it ok if I dont return any result from editActivity? Because I am updating the database after clicking save in editActivity class is that okey?

Comment: yes you can skip line `returnIntent.putExtra("result",YOUR_RESULT);`,
although you can send detect when user click `cancel` button instead of `save` and in this case you don't need to update list, for this you can use this `Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);        
finish();`

Comment: @Ondrej'zatokar'Tokár I update answer and add `cancel` result

Comment: Very nice answer, thank you, but I am still trying on resume. Anyway i will try both ways just for practice :).